# CodeBlocks C++ SDL2, PNG images cant be shown outside of the IDE

Tags: c++, image, load, sdl-image

In my project i have an *Animator* class, which has a method to load all sprites.

```
SDL_Texture*
Animator::CF_createImage_Load( SDL_Renderer* FP_renderer , std::string FV_path ,Uint8  FV_brC1,Uint8  FV_brC2,Uint8  FV_brC3, SDL_Window* window )
{
    SDL_Surface* loadSurface = IMG_Load(FV_path.c_str());

    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( FP_renderer , loadSurface );

    SDL_SetTextureColorMod(texture, FV_brC1, FV_brC2, FV_brC3);
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode( texture , SDL_BLENDMODE_ADD );

    return texture;

    SDL_FreeSurface( loadSurface );
    SDL_DestroyTexture( texture );
}
```

So if I run it within the IDE, it loads all sprites properly without any error. I just checked all pointers for debugging, all of them are ok, every image is shown properly as I said, but only within the IDE. If i build it and try to run the executable outside of the IDE ( in release or debug folder ), images are not shown at all.

There is one more thing. Font are loaded properly outside of the IDE, but Sprites aren't.

Comment: Are you using relative paths ("myfile.png" rather than "/mydata/myfile.png") to open the files and running afoul of a different initial working directory?

Comment: `char*    sdlPath       = SDL_GetBasePath();
            string   basePath      = string(sdlPath);` I am using this code to get the full path, It works properly within the IDE.

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but you are leaking `loadSurface`, because the part after the return statement is never reached. Anyway, you could avoid the surface althogether by using `IMG_LoadTexture`. Also, what's the point of the window parameter?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I will fix that leak. The window pointer is an unused var, I'll delete it, I used it before, but I forgot to deletet that.  Thank you :)